# Filter and Sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Hi I have two questions.

- Create filter to find any blanks cells and delete the entire row with it after which show all data
- Sort in one of the input on Range("E3:E") from A to Z

I tried this but keeps getting error "Method of object worksheet error"

```
    Set wsInput = Workbooks("InputB.xls").Worksheets("HC_MODULAR_BOARD_20180112")
    Set wsOutput = Workbooks("Output.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Ws2 = Workbooks("InputA.xls").Worksheets("Sheet0")


With wsInput

    'Error starts from here
     wsInput.Range("F3:F").AutoFilter Criteria1:="="
     wsInput.Range("F3:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
     wsInput.ShowAllData

     LastRow = wsInput.Cells(wsInput.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
         Rows("3:LastRow").Select
         .Sort.SortFields.Clear
         .Sort.SortFields.Add Key _
        :=Range("E3:LastRow"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal

    With wsInput.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:LastRow")
        .header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

    End With
```

I believe my sorting have some issues too please let me know if any of you see any mistakes.

Many thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Are all three workbooks open when you run the macro? If yes, do they all have worksheets with the names you use (check for extra spaces at the start and end of the worksheet names)?

Comment: Yes but this part of the program is only for one of the input and they have exactly the same name